# log4j BLOCKED when running intellij from other program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, synchronization, log4j, processbuilder

I get BLOCKED when running intellij from anther program(Shell) using ProccessBuilder
while the intellij use the log.
When I close the shell the program Intellij start running.
From what I understand the shell is sharing resources with intellij
how can I avoid this block?

> "Thread-6" prio=6 tid=0x000000000e01e000 nid=0x1a7c waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000014bce000]      java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)      at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:205)      - waiting to lock <0x00000000d2ef4ec0> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)      at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)      at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)      at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.info(IdeaLogger.java:176)      at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.idea.plugin.logger.RebelLog.info(RebelLog.java:22)      at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.idea.plugin.notifications.LicenseWatcher.checkLicense(LicenseWatcher.java:46)      at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.idea.plugin.notifications.LicenseWatcher.run(LicenseWatcher.java:19)

Comment: Looks like JRebel plug-in is asking for a license or something like that.

Comment: yes, but the problem is not only with Jrebel, with every plugin that trying to write to info log.